# How to process server side parameter sent from jquery datatables using Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask, datatables

I am having some issues in processing the parameters sent by jquery datatables 1.10 when server side processing is enabled. I initialized the datatable in the javascript side like this:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    'url': url,
                    'type': 'POST'
                },
                "columns": data
            } );
```

And receive the POST request in the Flask based server using this:

```
@app.route('/data/<data_key>', methods=['POST'])
def get_data(data_key):
    print request.form

    # do some processing here in order to filter data
    # ...

    return Response(json.dumps(data), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

In order to filter the data I tried to look inside request.form but the result is weird and can't be transformed easily to an array of objects. I get somthing like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict(
[
('columns[0][data]', u'ReportDate'), 
('draw', u'1'),
('columns[1][name]', u''), 
('columns[1][data]', u'FundName'),
('columns[0][orderable]', u'true'), 
('columns[1][searchable]', u'true'), 
('columns[1][orderable]', u'true'), 
('order[0][column]', u'0'), 
('columns[0][name]', u''), 
('order[0][dir]', u'asc'), 
('search[value]', u''), 
('columns[1][search][regex]', u'false'), 
('columns[0][search][value]', u''), 
('search[regex]', u'false'), 
('columns[1][search][value]', u''), 
('columns[0][search][regex]', u'false'), 
('start', u'0'), 
('length', u'10'), 
('columns[0][searchable]', u'true')
]
)
```

In the jquery datatables documentation they say:

> The order[i] and columns[i] parameters that are sent to the server are arrays of information:
>
> order[i] - is an array defining how many columns are being ordered upon - i.e. if the array length is 1, then a single column sort is being performed, otherwise a multi-column sort is being performed.
>
> columns[i] - an array defining all columns in the table.
>
> In both cases, i is an integer which will change to indicate the array value. In most modern server-side scripting environments this data will automatically be available to you as an array.

However, Flask provide this data as a simple dictionary, is there a way to transform it to an array of objects easily?

Comment: Have you tried request.get_json()? More info here:  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json

Comment: At first it gives an empty result, I then tried request.get_json(force=True) and then I get '400: Bad Request'. For the moment, I hooked the javascript code to send the data as a json payload.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get DataTable to send json

```
ajax: {
    url: "/api/data_table",
    type: "POST",
    data: function ( args ) {
      return { "args": JSON.stringify( args ) };
    }
},
```

In flask, parse the json

```
args = json.loads(request.values.get("args"))
columns = args.get("columns")
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record, the "Submit data as JSON in the request body" part is provided [here](http://datatables.net/manual/ajax) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little nifty package that I found https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser

```
from querystring_parser import parser
args = parser.parse(request.query_string)
print args['columns']
```